# Can we Clamp and Clip numbers mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

While programming I came up with a the following equation / workflow

```
clampValue = (value - minValueofRange) / (maxValueofRange - minValueofRange);
clippedValue = min(1, max(0, clampValue));
finalValue = clippedValue * scale;
```

Now the clipping ultimately causes an `if` and `else` in programming. Can we convert it completely to a mathematical equation?

**Edit:**

max and min are functions in c++ defined like:

```
int max(int v1, int v2){
    if(v1 > v2) return v1;
    else return v2;
}
```

Similar for the min() function

Comment: How are those not mathematical equations?

Comment: As per my understanding this is not
`clippedValue = min(1, max(0, clampValue));`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code. If the variable `max` is greater than the variable `min`, and the variable `value` is always at least `min`, then `clampValue` will always be at least $0$. So when you apply the `max` function you should get that `max(0, clampValue)` is always equal to `clampValue`. And if `value` is never bigger than `max`, then `clampValue` is never bigger than $1$, so when you apply the `min` function you get that `clippedValue` is always `clampValue`. So I don't understand what `clippedValue` is doing.

Comment: Value can be lower than the min and max Values. I'll update the code

Comment: Basit, I don't understand what you mean, I'm afraid. To what language do you think $\max$ and $\min$ belong to? These are mathematical constructs.

Comment: Oh sorry, max and min are functions e.g. in c++ and the code for max could be `if(v1 > v2) return v1 else return v2`

Comment: Well, that is how it works in mathematics, as well. I still don't understand what exactly are you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a functional expansion of the min/max function, use

$$ {\rm MinMax}(0,1,x) = \frac{ |x| - |x+|x|-2|}{4} + \frac{x+2}{4} $$

Or more generally

$$ {\rm MinMax}(x_{min},x_{max},x) = \frac{ |x-x_{min}| - | x+x_{min} + |x-x_{min}|-2 x_{max} |}{4} + \frac{x+2 x_{max}+x_{min}}{4} $$

Answer (score 4):

Using a piecewise function as in [T. Linnell's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2372161/26369) or simply writing something like $\min(1,\max(0,c))$ would be clear and absolutely fine in mathematics.

If you just happen to be curious about how to represent $\min$ and $\max$ in a different way, $\max(a,b)=\dfrac{|a-b|+a+b}{2}$ and $\min(a,b)=\dfrac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are after a branchless expression (otherwise you can stick to the $\min/\max$ definition).

I don't think there is anything in the floating-point mathematical functions that can help you. There are indeed built-in functions such as $\min$, $\max$ and $\text{abs}$ that you can use, but you don't know if they are implemented in a branchless way.

If you are looking for "by all means" optimization, you can hack into the floating-point representation and play with the sign bit, which is the most significant one.

For instance, in C, using a union with `{ int i; float f; }`, the expression `~(i >> 31) & i` implements the clamping of the negatives, $\max(0, f)$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, you're after a piecewise function:

$$f(x;a,b) = \begin{cases}0 & x < a\\ \frac{x-a}{b-a} &a\le x \le b\\ 1 &x > b\end{cases}$$

You can then multiply by whatever scalar factor you desire. I don't think there's a simpler way to do it in programming code than how you have. Ultimately, you need two comparisons to achieve the desired behaviour, which your code effectively has in the `max` and `min` functions.

Comment: Something like this would probably be the most common way of writing this in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

In sum you can display clipped value as:

$$
clamp = \frac {value - min(A)}{max(A) - min(A)}
$$

$$
max = \frac {\lvert clamp \rvert + clamp}{2}
$$

$$
min = \frac {\lvert 1 - max \rvert + 1 + max}{2}
$$

$$
clip = min; \ final =clip*scale 
$$

$$
final = \frac {\lvert 1 - \frac {\lvert \frac {value - min(A)}{max(A) - min(A)} \rvert + \frac {value - min(A)}{max(A) - min(A)}}{2} \rvert + 1 + \frac {\lvert \frac {value - min(A)}{max(A) - min(A)} \rvert + \frac {value - min(A)}{max(A) - min(A)}}{2}}{2} * scale
$$

or:

$$
scale * \frac{1}{4} * \Biggl(\frac{x}{a - b}- \sqrt{\biggl(\frac{b - x}{a - b} - \frac {\sqrt{ (b - x) ^2}}{\sqrt{(a - b)^2}} + 2\biggr)^2} + \frac {\sqrt{(b - x)^2}}{\sqrt{(a - b)^2}} - \frac {b}{a - b} + 2 \Biggr)
$$

$with\ a = max(A), \ b = min(A)\ and\ A=Range$